# Size of a Vector over time impact the program's performance?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, vector, size

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
int temp;
vector<int>numbers;
bool stop = false;

while (stop == false)
{
    cout << "\nInsert a number(-1 to quit): ";
    cin >> temp;
    numbers.push_back(temp);

    sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == numbers[i + 1])
        {
            cout << "Number duplicated!\n";
            numbers.erase(numbers.begin() + i);
            i--;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); j++)
    {
        cout << numbers[j] << ", ";
    }
    if (temp == -1)
        stop = true;
}
```

As you can see, it stores the number in a vector and that's fine. My question is, how the program is going to behave when the vector has stored, lets say, 5000 plus numbers? What's the impact, if any, on the memory and processor of the computer that is running the app?

Comment: There's an entire branch of computer science that deals with answers to this kind of a question. It's called "complexity". The first answer in the linked question provides more details.

Comment: Instead of that erase loop, why not use [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) and then `vector::erase`?

Comment: The provided link didn't answer my question. I didn't see anything regarding performance at least.

Comment: `numbers.erase(std::unique(numbers.begin(), numbers.end()), numbers.end());`  That is what you're loop boils down to.  Also, 5000 integers is tiny for something like this.

Comment: So if instead of 5000 imagine 500000, then what happens?

Comment: Why not try it and see what the performance is?

Comment: Do you want me to input 500000 integers? really? How? I'm not a programmer you know, just a beginner.

Comment: Ever hear of a loop and calling a random number generation function, like `rand()` or similar functions?  That's how you create these things without having to input numbers -- you generate the data.

Comment: Never tried that, gonna research it a little bit to see if can come up with this solution.

Comment: See [this](http://ideone.com/U3T81F)

Comment: OK thank you.
@Sam Varshavchik Still think its not a duplicated question.

Comment: It is certainly a duplicate. You claim "I didn't see anything regarding performance at least". I already explained that this is a "complexity" question, and the first answer in the linked question correctly gives you the complexity of `push_back()`. It states that it is "amortized O(1)". That directly answers your question about performance. Anyone else with C++ tag privileges could reverse it, if they disagreed; and I see that they have not.

Comment: But I didn't understand. Like I said before I'm a beginner and don't understand what's that is all about.

Comment: This is fine. Just consider this to be an excellent opportunity to learn something useful. See [the Wikipedia overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) for more information.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can you also give me an example on how to use this ´std::unique´ and ´vector::erase´ ?

Comment: @Baron -- Please see my previous comment concerning `std::unique`.   That one single line does everything your loop does (except for the extraneous `cout` statement).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well, for some reason its not working for me, at least when i tried populating my vector with the rand() function. There is lots of duplicated values.

Comment: @Baron You need to specify what you mean by "lots of duplicated values".  Of course values will be duplicated if the number of entries in the vector are large, and the range of the random number generator is small (0 - 32,767).  If you want a larger range, you can [try this](http://ideone.com/kdhvwF)